# pgfplot groupplot fillbetween

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I am trying to use the fillbetween package with combined with groupplot and I am having serious troubles.

Basically, what I want to have is the error plotted around my curves with a filled area. I am using groupplot to put them in a 2 by 2 matrix, and would try to define paths for the fillbetween package.

And here's my problem: both the lualatex and the pdflatex interpreters basically stop at any line within the groupplot that tries to name a path be it global or not.

My workaround was to define the paths outside the groupplots but that is not really good either, because preview now crops the right side of the groupplot...

I copied the whole code in, basically, the desired method to do this would be to remove the first four axises and change all the lines in the groupplot with [draw=none] to [draw=none,name path=something].

My final solution will be now to crop the picture manually, but here's my question: does anybody have a more elegant workaround?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2pt}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
1001.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
2001.0 0.1403 0.0 0.114025 0.158 0.0 0.0 
3001.0 0.2076 0.0 0.1977 0.217825 0.0 0.0 
4001.0 0.21935 0.0 0.20895 0.2291 0.0 0.0 
5001.0 0.22065 0.0 0.211325 0.2287 0.0 0.0 
6001.0 0.21755 0.0019 0.208575 0.2251 0.000525 0.0048 
7001.0 0.21755 0.0025 0.2089 0.227575 0.00065 0.006 
8001.0 0.2168 0.0026 0.206375 0.2247 0.00045 0.007325 
9001.0 0.21515 0.00335 0.2057 0.225525 0.0009 0.008875 
10001.0 0.2151 0.0035 0.20625 0.2257 0.000725 0.009475 
11001.0 0.21465 0.0039 0.205925 0.22555 0.000925 0.01015 
12001.0 0.21545 0.00415 0.20405 0.224525 0.00085 0.0128 
13001.0 0.2143 0.00435 0.20315 0.225225 0.000775 0.014875 
14001.0 0.2138 0.0047 0.20125 0.223075 0.0011 0.016 
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%the name path doesn't work inside groupplot so we have to define our fill paths outside outside
%this doesn't draw anything

\begin{axis}[axis lines=none]

\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigsmallfirstA] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigsmallfirstB] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigsmallsecondA] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigsmallsecondB] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data.dat};

\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=none]

\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigbigfirstA] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigbigfirstB] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigbigsecondA] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigbigsecondB] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=none]

\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallsmallfirstA] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallsmallfirstB] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallsmallsecondA] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallsmallsecondB] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=none]

\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallbigfirstA] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallbigfirstB] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallbigsecondA] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallbigsecondB] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data.dat};
\end{axis}

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2, horizontal sep=2cm,
xlabels at=edge bottom
},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
scaled y ticks = false,
scaled x ticks = false,
xlabel=time (week),
xtick pos=left,
ytick pos=left,
]

\node at (-1.5,1.2) [anchor=west, rotate=90] {\bfseries{high prevalence}};
\node at (-1.5,-5.5) [anchor=west, rotate=90] {\bfseries{low prevalence}};
\node at (-1,6.3) [anchor=west] {\bfseries{second strain with 0\% advantage}};
\node at (8.1,6.3) [anchor=west] {\bfseries{second strain with 25\% advantage}};

\node at (0.7,5) {(a)};
\node at (9.7,5) {(b)};
\node at (0.7,-2) {(c)};
\node at (9.7,-2) {(d)};


\nextgroupplot[legend columns=-1,legend style={{draw=none,column sep=1ex, at={(1.8,1.3), anchor=north west},
/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=2cm}}},
legend entries={first strain, second strain}]


\addplot[color=blue, line width = 1.0] table[x index=0, y index=1] {data.dat};
\addplot[color=red, line width = 1.0,loosely dashed] table[x index=0, y index=2] {data.dat};
%you have to plot the extremes of the plot to get the same scale to ...
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data.dat};
\addplot[blue,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=bigsmallfirstA and bigsmallfirstB];
\addplot[red,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=bigsmallsecondA and bigsmallsecondB];


\nextgroupplot
\addplot[color=blue, line width = 1.0] table[x index=0, y index=1] {data.dat};
\addplot[color=red, line width = 1.0,loosely dashed] table[x index=0, y index=2] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data.dat};
\addplot[blue,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=bigbigfirstA and bigbigfirstB];
\addplot[red,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=bigbigsecondA and bigbigsecondB];

\nextgroupplot
\addplot[color=blue, line width = 1.0] table[x index=0, y index=1] {data.dat};
\addplot[color=red, line width = 1.0,loosely dashed] table[x index=0, y index=2] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data.dat};
\addplot[blue,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=smallsmallfirstA and smallsmallfirstB];
\addplot[red,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=smallsmallsecondA and smallsmallsecondB];

\nextgroupplot
\addplot[color=blue, line width = 1] table[x index=0, y index=1] {data.dat};
\addplot[color=red, line width = 1,loosely dashed] table[x index=0, y index=2] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data.dat};
\addplot[blue,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=smallbigfirstA and smallbigfirstB];
\addplot[red,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=smallbigsecondA and smallbigsecondB];
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX! It would be nice if you could also add a sample data file (e.g. with `filecontents`), or use some dummy `coordinates` instead of `table [...] {...};`, so that we can copy and compile your example directly. That helps us help you.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks:) as per your rather relevant request I added dummy data (the same for all the panels). thanks in advance!

Comment: Hm, `name path global` plots works just fine inside `groupplots` here, with an up to date TeX Live 2013. (A little tip unrelated to that issue: you can place nodes relative to the different groupplot axes, try for example `\node at (group c1r1.west) [xshift=-1.7cm,anchor=center, rotate=90] {\bfseries{high prevalence}};` after the `groupplots` environment.)

Comment: @sudosensei Well, technically yes (probably:D), but in practice I was baffled by the exact problem happening (i.e. name path not working in groupplots). I think I saw like two-three answers on the site on how to make something like this, but I wanted to get the new library to work.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Hmm, that's interesting, I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and installed texlive-full from the repo and used tlmgr to update pgfplots to 1.10. My version is 
TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1

I'm not sure if it is the latest or not (should be latest in the repo though).

Comment: Can you use `tlmgr` with the TL from Debian repos? Have you also got PGF 3.0? I use the TL from TUG.org.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the unrelated tip, it is much nicer than placing by hand:D 

And the problem was pgf, yes I didn't realize that the backend would need an update as well ... Thanks, it works like a charm now!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Does the preview work for you as well? Because for me it still cuts off the right side. What it actually does, is it sets the width according to just the groupplot and if I add text to the right it shifts everything a bit right, and thus cutting off a but of the plot.

Comment: No, it doesn't actually. Didn't notice that before. I usually use the `standalone` class though, and that works fine. Just remove all the `preview` stuff, and use `\documentclass[class=scrartcl,14pt]{standalone}` instead, doesn't look like anything is cut off then.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you're a hero :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Torbjørn T.'s comments and expanding it with the problem of using the newest pgfplot if you installed texlive from the Ubuntu repo:

To use the latest pgfplots library you need to update pgf as well (and to use tlmgr, you'll probably need xzdec as well):

```
sudo apt-get install xzdec
tlmgr init-usertree
tlmgr install pgfplots
tlmgr install pgf
```

After that using name path in groupplots work fine.

The working code:

```
\documentclass[class=scrartcl,14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmathfont{Arial}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}


\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.001000000000000000e+03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.001000000000000000e+03 1.393999999999999961e-01 1.089399999999999952e-01 1.598050000000000026e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.001000000000000000e+03 2.077499999999999902e-01 1.971475000000000033e-01 2.176500000000000101e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.001000000000000000e+03 2.186250000000000138e-01 2.098974999999999869e-01 2.270500000000000018e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.001000000000000000e+03 2.204000000000000126e-01 2.109475000000000100e-01 2.292500000000000093e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.001000000000000000e+03 2.177999999999999936e-01 2.086850000000000094e-01 2.270000000000000073e-01 2.174999999999999850e-03 5.000000000000000104e-04 5.100000000000000366e-03
7.001000000000000000e+03 2.184500000000000053e-01 2.081000000000000072e-01 2.275449999999999973e-01 1.949999999999999910e-03 2.000000000000000096e-04 6.100000000000000387e-03
8.001000000000000000e+03 2.172000000000000042e-01 2.073500000000000065e-01 2.266174999999999995e-01 1.899999999999999996e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 7.117499999999999695e-03
9.001000000000000000e+03 2.175249999999999961e-01 2.075849999999999917e-01 2.269150000000000056e-01 1.850000000000000082e-03 9.249999999999999867e-05 8.200000000000000691e-03
1.000100000000000000e+04 2.170749999999999902e-01 2.064999999999999891e-01 2.267975000000000130e-01 2.000000000000000042e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 9.197500000000000814e-03
1.100100000000000000e+04 2.168499999999999872e-01 2.063500000000000056e-01 2.263000000000000012e-01 2.200000000000000133e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 1.105000000000000079e-02
1.200100000000000000e+04 2.165249999999999952e-01 2.048375000000000057e-01 2.270149999999999946e-01 2.449999999999999921e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 1.179999999999999973e-02
1.300100000000000000e+04 2.161500000000000088e-01 2.048500000000000043e-01 2.258300000000000030e-01 2.700000000000000143e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 1.204000000000000035e-02
1.400100000000000000e+04 2.159999999999999976e-01 2.040150000000000019e-01 2.261450000000000127e-01 3.050000000000000194e-03 1.499999999999999869e-04 1.349500000000000005e-02
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.001000000000000000e+03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.001000000000000000e+03 1.393999999999999961e-01 1.089399999999999952e-01 1.598050000000000026e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.001000000000000000e+03 2.077499999999999902e-01 1.971475000000000033e-01 2.176500000000000101e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.001000000000000000e+03 2.186250000000000138e-01 2.098974999999999869e-01 2.270500000000000018e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.001000000000000000e+03 2.204000000000000126e-01 2.109475000000000100e-01 2.292500000000000093e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.001000000000000000e+03 2.153500000000000136e-01 2.057950000000000057e-01 2.251549999999999940e-01 5.599999999999999943e-03 1.745000000000000023e-03 1.295499999999999950e-02
7.001000000000000000e+03 2.101000000000000090e-01 1.942399999999999960e-01 2.224599999999999911e-01 1.359999999999999924e-02 2.739999999999999814e-03 3.477000000000000229e-02
8.001000000000000000e+03 1.975999999999999979e-01 1.646700000000000108e-01 2.177399999999999891e-01 3.185000000000000331e-02 5.335000000000000332e-03 7.951500000000000234e-02
9.001000000000000000e+03 1.718000000000000083e-01 1.193000000000000033e-01 2.112249999999999961e-01 6.940000000000000335e-02 1.305000000000000084e-02 1.462749999999999884e-01
1.000100000000000000e+04 1.287999999999999978e-01 7.374999999999999611e-02 1.962899999999999923e-01 1.289500000000000091e-01 3.244999999999999968e-02 2.115200000000000136e-01
1.100100000000000000e+04 8.147500000000000575e-02 3.836749999999999883e-02 1.695250000000000090e-01 1.985750000000000015e-01 7.426499999999999768e-02 2.616324999999999901e-01
1.200100000000000000e+04 4.440000000000000197e-02 1.840249999999999872e-02 1.262675000000000047e-01 2.504000000000000115e-01 1.380474999999999897e-01 2.905325000000000268e-01
1.300100000000000000e+04 2.164999999999999911e-02 7.817499999999999796e-03 7.922999999999999488e-02 2.845500000000000251e-01 2.019749999999999879e-01 3.071825000000000250e-01
1.400100000000000000e+04 9.650000000000000591e-03 3.017500000000000217e-03 4.343000000000000332e-02 3.001499999999999724e-01 2.539449999999999763e-01 3.158799999999999941e-01
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data3.dat}
1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.001000000000000000e+03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.001000000000000000e+03 1.460000000000000013e-02 4.197499999999999842e-03 2.730250000000000038e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.001000000000000000e+03 2.717500000000000124e-02 1.113250000000000003e-02 3.660499999999999865e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.001000000000000000e+03 3.052500000000000005e-02 1.990000000000000102e-02 3.870250000000000079e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.001000000000000000e+03 3.139999999999999736e-02 2.214750000000000052e-02 3.955249999999999738e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.001000000000000000e+03 3.155000000000000165e-02 2.375000000000000028e-02 3.915249999999999980e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.001000000000000000e+03 3.192500000000000199e-02 2.429500000000000062e-02 3.944999999999999896e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.001000000000000000e+03 2.985000000000000153e-02 2.220000000000000098e-02 3.725250000000000089e-02 2.749999999999999840e-03 8.499999999999999526e-04 6.702500000000000124e-03
9.001000000000000000e+03 2.895000000000000004e-02 2.056749999999999898e-02 3.723250000000000171e-02 2.500000000000000052e-03 2.000000000000000096e-04 9.782499999999999529e-03
1.000100000000000000e+04 2.794999999999999915e-02 1.907500000000000168e-02 3.610000000000000014e-02 2.399999999999999790e-03 5.000000000000000240e-05 1.187500000000000014e-02
1.100100000000000000e+04 2.744999999999999871e-02 1.590000000000000094e-02 3.700250000000000067e-02 2.724999999999999992e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 1.332000000000000024e-02
1.200100000000000000e+04 2.732499999999999860e-02 1.389999999999999916e-02 3.645000000000000323e-02 2.925000000000000083e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 1.596500000000000002e-02
1.300100000000000000e+04 2.634999999999999842e-02 1.177500000000000074e-02 3.596250000000000141e-02 3.449999999999999942e-03 5.000000000000000240e-05 1.818749999999999881e-02
1.400100000000000000e+04 2.552499999999999908e-02 1.000500000000000000e-02 3.497249999999999664e-02 4.599999999999999922e-03 1.424999999999999943e-04 2.038749999999999937e-02
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data4.dat}
1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.001000000000000000e+03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.001000000000000000e+03 1.460000000000000013e-02 4.197499999999999842e-03 2.730250000000000038e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.001000000000000000e+03 2.717500000000000124e-02 1.113250000000000003e-02 3.660499999999999865e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.001000000000000000e+03 3.052500000000000005e-02 1.990000000000000102e-02 3.870250000000000079e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.001000000000000000e+03 3.139999999999999736e-02 2.214750000000000052e-02 3.955249999999999738e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.001000000000000000e+03 3.155000000000000165e-02 2.375000000000000028e-02 3.915249999999999980e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.001000000000000000e+03 3.192500000000000199e-02 2.429500000000000062e-02 3.944999999999999896e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.001000000000000000e+03 2.910000000000000087e-02 2.109750000000000167e-02 3.640000000000000180e-02 6.049999999999999822e-03 1.897500000000000098e-03 1.345000000000000015e-02
9.001000000000000000e+03 2.485000000000000056e-02 1.513499999999999915e-02 3.420499999999999929e-02 1.305000000000000084e-02 2.050000000000000173e-03 3.030000000000000054e-02
1.000100000000000000e+04 1.962500000000000008e-02 8.899999999999999925e-03 3.219999999999999946e-02 2.390000000000000110e-02 2.599999999999999881e-03 4.624999999999999944e-02
1.100100000000000000e+04 1.319999999999999993e-02 4.060000000000000241e-03 2.938999999999999946e-02 3.774999999999999883e-02 5.449999999999999983e-03 5.909999999999999976e-02
1.200100000000000000e+04 7.649999999999999682e-03 1.299999999999999940e-03 2.605000000000000024e-02 4.984999999999999848e-02 1.220000000000000077e-02 6.619999999999999496e-02
1.300100000000000000e+04 3.899999999999999821e-03 2.999999999999999737e-04 2.125250000000000056e-02 5.787500000000000283e-02 2.262499999999999928e-02 7.080000000000000182e-02
1.400100000000000000e+04 1.699999999999999905e-03 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.285000000000000031e-02 6.235000000000000264e-02 3.817000000000000254e-02 7.255749999999999700e-02
\end{filecontents}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{100, 0, 150}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{34, 139, 34}

\begin{document}
%~ \begin{preview}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2, horizontal sep=2cm,
xlabels at=edge bottom
},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
scaled y ticks = false,
scaled x ticks = false,
%~ xlabel=time (week),
xlabel=time (year),
xtick pos=left,
ytick pos=left,
]




\nextgroupplot[legend columns=-1,legend style={{draw=none,column sep=1ex, at={(2,1.3), anchor=north west},
/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=5cm}}},
legend entries={first strain, second strain},
ymax = 0.35,
ymin = -0.05,
ytick= {0,0.1,0.2,0.3},
minor y tick num = {1},
%~ xtick ={1000,5000},
xtick ={0,5218,10436,15654},
xticklabels={$0$,$100$,$200$,$300$}
]
%to switch to years divide be 52.18
\addlegendimage{no markers,myblue,line width=2.0}
\addlegendimage{no markers,myred,line width=2.0,loosely dashed}

\addplot[color=myblue, line width = 1.0] table[x index=0, y index=1] {data.dat};
\addplot[color=myred, line width = 1.0,loosely dashed] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data.dat};
%you have to plot the extremes of the plot to get the same scale to ...
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigsmallfirstA] table[x index=0, y index=2] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigsmallfirstB] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigsmallsecondA] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigsmallsecondB] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data.dat};
\addplot[myblue,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=bigsmallfirstA and bigsmallfirstB];
\addplot[myred,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=bigsmallsecondA and bigsmallsecondB];


\nextgroupplot[
ymax = 0.35,
ymin = -0.05,
ytick= {0,0.1,0.2,0.3},
minor y tick num = {1},
%~ xtick ={1000,5000},
xtick ={0,5218,10436,15654},
xticklabels={$0$,$100$,$200$,$300$}
]
\addplot[color=myblue, line width = 1.0] table[x index=0, y index=1] {data2.dat};
\addplot[color=myred, line width = 1.0,loosely dashed] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data2.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigbigfirstA] table[x index=0, y index=2] {data2.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigbigfirstB] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data2.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigbigsecondA] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data2.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigbigsecondB] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data2.dat};
\addplot[myblue,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=bigbigfirstA and bigbigfirstB];
\addplot[myred,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=bigbigsecondA and bigbigsecondB];

\nextgroupplot[
ymax = 0.08,
ymin = -0.005,
ytick= {0,0.03,0.06},
minor y tick num = {1},
%~ xtick ={1000,7000},
xtick ={0,5218,10436,15654},
xticklabels={$0$,$100$,$200$,$300$}
]
\addplot[color=myblue, line width = 1.0] table[x index=0, y index=1] {data3.dat};
\addplot[color=myred, line width = 1.0,loosely dashed] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data3.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallsmallfirstA] table[x index=0, y index=2] {data3.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallsmallfirstB] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data3.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallsmallsecondA] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data3.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallsmallsecondB] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data3.dat};
\addplot[myblue,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=smallsmallfirstA and smallsmallfirstB];
\addplot[myred,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=smallsmallsecondA and smallsmallsecondB];

\nextgroupplot[
ymax = 0.08,
ymin = -0.005,
ytick= {0,0.03,0.06},
minor y tick num = {1},
%~ xtick ={1000,7000},
xtick ={0,5218,10436,15654},
xticklabels={$0$,$100$,$200$,$300$}
]
\addplot[color=myblue, line width = 1] table[x index=0, y index=1] {data4.dat};
\addplot[color=myred, line width = 1,loosely dashed] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data4.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallbigfirstA] table[x index=0, y index=2] {data4.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallbigfirstB] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data4.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallbigsecondA] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data4.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallbigsecondB] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data4.dat};
\addplot[myblue,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=smallbigfirstA and smallbigfirstB];
\addplot[myred,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=smallbigsecondA and smallbigsecondB];
\end{groupplot}

\node at (group c1r1.west) [xshift=-1.7cm,anchor=center, rotate=90] {\bfseries{high prevalence}};
\node at (group c1r2.west) [xshift=-1.7cm,anchor=center, rotate=90] {\bfseries{low prevalence}};
\node at (group c1r1.north) [yshift= 0.7 cm, anchor=center] {\bfseries{second strain with 0\% advantage}};
\node at (group c2r1.north) [yshift= 0.7 cm, anchor=center] {\bfseries{second strain with 25\% advantage}};

\node at (group c1r1.north west) [xshift=0cm,yshift=0.35cm,anchor=north east]{\bfseries{(a)}};
\node at (group c2r1.north west) [xshift=0cm,yshift=0.35cm,anchor=north east]{\bfseries{(b)}};
\node at (group c1r2.north west) [xshift=0cm,yshift=0.35cm,anchor=north east]{\bfseries{(c)}};
\node at (group c2r2.north west) [xshift=0cm,yshift=0.35cm,anchor=north east]{\bfseries{(d)}};
\end{tikzpicture}

%~ \end{preview}
\end{document}
```

This should produce this:
[image]

Comment: Could you also paste the code with the solution? Have you changed any code from the one shown in the question section? If I compile the code from the question I get misaligned and overlapped plots.

Comment: Not counting the labels on the x axis (it has large numbers and they overlap), it work fine for me.

Comment: I edited the answer with the much nicer way of doing it.